# Creating a vertical slider HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit

I am trying to create my own HTML element that looks like this:

The look I want to create: [image: I am trying to create this look]
My attempt: [image: My attempt at replication]

The widget is only for a iPad version of the website & I cannot unfortunately use JQuery.

**My problem:** I am trying to add a slider/arrow to the widget but I dont know how? Is there a webkit appearance that has an arrow slider on it? Is it possible to have a slider arrow on the widget?

My code:

```
<div style="background-color: rgb(191, 326, 383); width: 200px;">
    <ul style="list-style: none; -webkit-appearance: slider-vertical; width: 200px; height: 300px; margin: 0;">
        <li>jddsjh -</li>
        <li>jddsjh -</li>
        <li>jddsjh -</li>
        <li>jddsjh -</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why can't you use jQuery? You're going to have to create an asset for the handle or render one with CSS but to my knowledge there isn't a webkit-appearance for it. To make it functional you will essentially have to re-write jQuery UI's draggable(). Not prohibitively difficult but not something I would be enthusiastic about.

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/XyJWa/

Comment: @user1090389 Thats perfect, you should make an answer so I can accept. Have no idea how that even works but its what I need :P

Comment: @JakeM np, it an HTML5 input type, it's called range. You can look up some if it's attributes, I just took and it and rotated it 90 degrees...

Comment: @JakeM the `top` and `position` CSS is not required but it renders weird on jsFiddle

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```css
input[type="range"] {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    top:100px;
   
}
```

```html
<input type="range">
```

Comment: Just complementing your answer, you can also style the controls: http://jsfiddle.net/Wv6cU/