# iPad vertical input-slider

Tags: css, slider

I'm using jQuery UI to create a vertical input-range slider ([this style to be exact](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#slider-vertical)). 
I would rather use a more lightweight framework like Zepto, or of course native JS to create this slider.

My specific use-case is for iPad (iOS 4.3+) only, so only webkit-support is required. CSS3 styling of `<input type="range" />` is not an option because it cannot be styled in vertical orientation, and `rotate(90deg)` doesn't behave correctly on iOS. Also, iOS 4.3 does not support it at all.

Can anyone point me to a better solution?

Comment: Some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5001464/google-chrome-vertical-input-type-range - or-  http://jsfiddle.net/ArondeParon/SPjsf/15/

Comment: Not relevant to my question, like I said: "...cannot be styled in vertical orientation".

Answer (score 0):

This may be what you're after:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8696975/1170982

I'm not sure how the rotate3d transform doesn't behave correctly in iOS - never encountered any issues myself, but you could also apply the 'vertical-slider' value to a transform:

```
-webkit-appearance: slider-vertical;
```

Here's a wee preview:

http://jsfiddle.net/pSfSx/

Comment: Ah, someone already answered it at the end of @ErikdR 's link.